# Incorrect image matching results despite differences (human fingerprints)

Tags: python, opencv, fingerprint

I want to use python to compared two images to check whether they are the same or not, I want to use this for fingerprint functionality in django app to validate whether the provided fingerprint is matches the one stored in the database. I have decided to use OpenCV for this purpose, utilizing `ORB_create` with `detectAndCompute` and providing the provided fingerprint to the `BFMatcher`. However, with the code below, when attempting to match the images, it consistently return True, while the provided images are not the same, along with the `print` statment "Images are the same".

```
def compared_fingerprint(image1, image2):

    finger1 = cv2.imread(image1, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    finger2 = cv2.imread(image2, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    orb = cv2.ORB_create()

    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(finger1, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(finger2, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
    threshold = 0.7

    similar = len(matches) > threshold * len(keypoints1)

    if similar:
        print('Images are the same')
        return similar
    else:
        print('Images are not the same')
        return similar

result = compared_fingerprint('c.jpg', 'a.jpg')
print(result)
```

With the provided images, the function supposed to return the second statement, since, they are not the same, I thought, it was the `threshold` assign to `0.7`, and when I increase the `threshold` to `1.7`, it return the second statement saying: "Images are not the same" False, but when I try to make the images to be the same, I mean: `result = compared_fingerprint('a.jpg', 'a.jpg')`, it's still return "Images are not the same" False.

**a.jpg**

[image: this is an a image]

**c.jpg**

[image: this is an c image]

Comment: can you provide example pictures that illustrate where exactly you draw the line between "same or not"

Comment: those matchers ALWAYS find matches. have you looked at the results? run your code in a debugger. [mre]

Comment: that `0.7` constant comes from "Lowe's ratio test" but you aren't doing that, you are doing something completely different. this stuff requires formal education or at least self-directed learning. you can't "wing" this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the matcher does not draw any line to the result images sir.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sir, You can use this code to determine whether the matcher draws the line or not. to me, it does nothing.

Comment: when I said "draw the line" in my first comment, I mean "to distinguish". I asked for example pictures. however, that doesn't matter because this code is functionally not able to do what you intend.

Comment: @Bubble your approach is very inefficient an likely to produce poor results. You should use partial hashing to detect duplicates (look at how de dupe works).

Comment: *perceptual* hashing. that doesn't absolve the engineer from understanding what any method is invariant or sensitive to, and whether that fits the task. -- if this is about literal human fingerprints, then this whole approach strikes me as unsuitable. literature review required. if this is *not* about human fingerprints but about "fingerprinting" of arbitrary pictures... oh well

Comment: You need to include sample images, otherwise your code is not reproducible.

Comment: @stateMachine check the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fingerprints are matched using features *specific to fingerprints*. Fingerprints are mostly just ridges running in parallel, so that's boring. The interesting and identifying features are swirls (ridges curve around), ridge *ends*, short "island" segments (and their lengths), forks, ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint#Fingerprint_verification

Generic local feature descriptors may work but are not specific to fingerprints.

You'll need to do the literature research to learn what feature descriptors have performed well *on fingerprints*.

Features then need to match in a spatially consistent manner. Rotation and translation don't matter. Some stretching and even less shearing are tolerable. Perspective components are extrmely unlikely. If you estimate a transform, you'll need to assess how much it contorts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just echoing @Christoph-Rackwitz here, but a feature-matching algorithm is unsuitable for this scenario, at least on its own. It will match small sub-patches of one image to the other, and since all fingerprint images *look* similar, ORB will find a sufficient bunch of similar patches as well (and, consequently, your approach will always decide they are indeed similar).

At a minimum, you would need to spatially match the two images using e.g. `findHomography` (see https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/ for an example), and then count the ratio of inliers vs. outliers between your feature points and the calculated homography. The `drawMatches` function will help visualize this (in case of a good match, you will mostly see parallel lines).